# save the results of a macro without opening the file

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation, save, vba

I have a macro in excel which refreshs some data from external sources. I want to create a code which basically run this macro without opening the excel file every day and save the result.

I have come up with a code which run the macro but for some reason the saving functions does not work.

Here is the code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\Users\Huwyler\Desktop\testMacro.xlsm'!Sheet1.addDate"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

and the error message: "Save method of Application class failed"

I need some answer for:

1. solve the saving problem
2. How to get this script to run automatically let's say every day?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's 2 questions... So for the 2nd one, just google *task scheduler for vba*, see http://velin-georgiev-blog.appspot.com/blog/fully-automated-excel-reporting-by-using-windows-task-scheduler-vba-and-simple-vba-functions-library

Comment: Take a look here for the first question - http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm. And put a bit more of the code, e.g. the initialization.

Comment: Yes the second one would just require a bit of googling.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar task in few steps:

1. make a .bat file which will launch the excel file based on windows task scheduler, inside this file put the below code:

`C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\testfolder\newexclname.xlsm`

2. in the excel edit the connection properties to be refreshed on file open.
3. put the below in workbook open sub:

   `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim folderpath, newexclname as String
   folderpath = "C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\testfolder\"
   newexclname = "textexl"
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
       ChDir folderpath 
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= folderpath & newexclname & ".xlsx" _
           , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
           ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges = True
   End Sub`

Hope this can solve you question.